# Company's app distribution to the company's customers

Tags: iphone

I would like to distribute an application where only registered and paying customers of our company can have access to. The app would be distributed in the app store for free and users would have to log in with the registered details to use the application.

The problem is that the app will have certain amount of functionality based on what the registered customers have paid us. For example customer A paid us $500 for the registration and hence he will have the full functionality of this application. On the other hand customer B paid us $250 and this customer will only have half of the functionality of this application.

Is my company allowed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this sort of thing in the App Store, if that's what you're asking?

You might be able to do something similar via the iOS Developer Enterprise Program instead: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: But the enterprise program is only the in-house app for the company. I am not sure about this as we are planning to sell this app to the customers of our company.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be carefull about Apple's rules for app content. I am far from an expert so I am only suggesting you look into the possibility that Apple will view this as an end around their In App Purchase.

From what we have learned in our research is Apple doesn't allow the sale of app content or features that are not sold through Apple's approved purchase systems. A magazine app that sells a subscription qualifies as selling content. An app that provides additional functionality based on a monetary transaction also falls into this situation. You can sell a widget (food order, event ticket or clothing) without running afoul of this.

If you go down this path, you should not make mention of the payment difference affecting the features in the app. Apple will want a login that gives them full access to the app features. You may want to consider publishing two apps. One fr the different kind of customer.

Perhaps someone else can shed more light on this issue.

Comment: Indeed. This is the thing that I am worried about. My company wants me to only distribute with some features available or not. Looking at it commercially, it doesn't make a difference since customers pay to us directly in the first place. So yeah if anyone has more experience in this thing , it would be helpful if he can share his opinion...

Comment: "...it doesn't make a difference since customers pay to us directly in the first place." Actually that is exactly the issue that violates the Apple plan. Because Apple, like the mob, wants their 30%. We have had to educate our company and clients that Apple is not some small vendor they can "convince" to change rules or get a better rate. You will have to hope Apple doesn't catch on to what is really happening.

Comment: Exactly, since i would have to use in-app purchase in the first place then I might as well sell this application at a fixed base price which gives basic functionality and then the customer can unlock features based on in-app purchase. Should I do it this way?